# PHPでメールアドレス形式の文字列を名前とメールアドレスに分割する方法

Tags: php, mail

お世話になります。
下記のようなメールアドレス形式の文字列があったとします。

```
テスト <test@example.com>
```

PHPでこの文字列を名前部分（例でいうと「テスト」の部分）とメールアドレスの部分（例でいうと「test@example.com」の部分）にわけて取得したいのですが、何かよい方法はないでしょうか。
やはり正規表現で取り出すしかないでしょうか。
何かよい方法があれば、アドバイスをいただけますと幸いです。
以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 参考: 英語版での類似質問と回答 - [Parse e-mail addresses with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7599346)

Comment: ありがとうございます。mailparseライブラリを使うのが一番楽ですね。ただ、ライブラリを導入できないサーバーだと困りますが。

Answer (score 1):

以前に回答した正規表現ではかなり不十分だったこと、また、正規表現で行うのは難しいということで、結局ライブラリを利用することにしました。
mailparseという拡張機能をインストールした上で、下記のようにすると、簡単に取得できました。

```
var_dump(mailparse_rfc822_parse_addresses('"テスト" <test@example.com>'));
```

Answer (score -1):

こんにちは、速度面等からの理由で正規表現を使わずに、
文字列から、なにか取り出したいケースで、かつ入力値が予測できる場合、
私はexplodeを用いることが多いです。

```
$a = "テスト<test@example.com>";
$b = explode("<",$a);
echo $b[0].PHP_EOL;
echo str_replace(">","",$b[1]).PHP_EOL;
```

多分、正規表現の方がこのケースでは見通しがよくなると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。名前部分には小なり記号を入れることも可能なようなので、explodeでは少し難しい気がします。やはり、このような場合、正規表現で書いた方がいい気がしたので、一応書いてみました。回答としてサンプルを掲載したので、不十分な点等があれば、アドバイスいただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score -1):

とりあえず、正規表現で書いてみました。
ただ、もしかしたら不十分な点とかがあるかもしれません。
何かお気づきの点があれば、教えていただけますと幸いです。

```
<?php
var_dump(separate_mail_address("\"テスト\" <test@example.com>"));

// 名前とメールアドレスを分割して、配列にして返す関数
function separate_mail_address($address){
// 正規表現でマッチするかどうか調べる
if (preg_match("/^(.*?)<(.*?)>$/", $address, $matches) === 1){
// 名前部分を取り出す
$name = $matches[1];
// 名前部分が空っぽじゃなかったときの処理
if ($name !== ""){
// 「<」までで1つのパターンとして取り出しているため、末尾の空白を削除する
$name = rtrim($name, " ");
// 名前部分にダブルクォーテーションは利用できないので、削除する
$name = str_replace('"', "", $name);
}
// メールアドレスの部分を取り出す
$address = $matches[2];
// 名前とアドレスを配列にしてセットする
$ret = array($name, $address);
// 正規表現にマッチしなかったときの処理
}else{
// 渡されたアドレスをそのまま配列にしてセットする
$ret = array($address);
}
// 結果を返す
return $ret;
}
?>
```

Comment: 参考までに、メールの正規表現を可能な限り正確に書くと　http://www.din.or.jp/~ohzaki/mail_regex.htm の様になります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。サイトを拝見したところ、記載されている正規表現はPerlでの動作を前提に書かれているようですが、PHPにPerlの正規表現は流用できるのでしょうか。それにしても、正規表現で書くと、かなり長くなりますね。私の回答で書いたのは、かなりがっつりとしか判定していないので、いろいろ不具合がありそうです。

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ja/reference.pcre.pattern.differences.php に正規表現 処理の違いが書いてあります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ざっと見てみましたが、結構違いますね。なかなか難しそうです。